# cppcheck não ignora arquivos da biblioteca da espressif quando executado através da pipeline do jenkins

Tags: c, jenkins, integração-contínua, iot

Gostaria de fazer a analise estática apenas dos arquivos do meu projeto, pois a biblioteca de terceiro geralmente esta dockerizada e estável, não sendo necessário ficar realizando a analise estática toda vez de algo imutável, porém estou tendo alguns problemas quando executo através do jenkins para fazer a integração continua. Para fazer o build do meu projeto IoT eu utilizo a imagem docker oficial da espressif e tenho como resultado uma pasta build com o `compile_commands.json` dentro dela

Acesso a máquina onde tem o jenkins instalado via ssh e consigo executar o comando abaixo:

`cppcheck --project=$PWD/ESPComm/build/compile_commands.json -i /opt/esp/ --inline-suppr --enable=all --suppress=missingInclude --suppress=unmatchedSuppression --suppressions-list=.suppressions --inconclusive --std=c11 --xml --xml-version=2 --std=c11 2> cppcheck.xml`

Já abri o arquivo cppcheck.xml que foi gerado e como era de ser esperado, foi ignorado as bibliotecas do `/opt/esp` (quando nao passo o argumento `-i /opt/esp/` é feito a analise de cerca de 855 itens da biblioteca da espressif), a analise estática basicamente foi feita apenas sobre os arquivos do meu projeto (28 itens)

Entretanto quando executo o comando no pipeline do jenkins com uma segunda imagem contendo ferramentas de analise estatica:

```
stage('Load docker image with tools for Static Analysis') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'mytools/tools-cde-image:0.1'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            stages{
                stage('Static Analysis') {
                    steps {
                        sh '''
                            pwd
                            ls -a
                            '''
                        sh 'sloccount --wide --details $WORKSPACE/ESPComm/build > sloccount.sc'
                        sloccountPublish encoding: '', pattern: 'sloccount.sc'
                        sh 'cppcheck --project=$PWD/ESPComm/build/compile_commands.json -i /opt/esp/ --inline-suppr --enable=all --suppress=missingInclude --suppress=unmatchedSuppression --suppressions-list=.suppressions --inconclusive --std=c11 --xml --xml-version=2 --std=c11 2> cppcheck.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Tenho no log essa saída de erro:

```
+ cppcheck --project=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iot-proj-TEST/ESPComm/build/compile_commands.json -i/opt/esp/ --inline-suppr --enable=all --suppress=missingInclude --suppress=unmatchedSuppression --suppressions-list=.suppressions --inconclusive --std=c11 --xml --xml-version=2 --std=c11
cppcheck: error: '/opt/esp/idf/components/xtensa/debug_helpers.c' from compilation database does not exist
cppcheck: error: failed to load project '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iot-proj-TEST/ESPComm/build/compile_commands.json'. An error occurred.
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Abri o arquivo compile_commands.json para conferir e retirei algumas amostras:

```
1 - "file": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iot-proj/ESPComm/build/project_elf_src.c"
2 - "file": "/opt/esp/idf/components/xtensa/debug_helpers.c" >> NESSE ARQUIVO QUE JÁ APARECE O PROBLEMA QUE O ARQUIVO NAO EXISTE
857 - "file": "/opt/esp/idf/components/wifi_provisioning/proto-c/wifi_constants.pb-c.c"
858 - "file": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/iot-proj/ESPComm/main/alarm_table.c"
```